# Retaining values on input after file submission and manual defined error occurs

Tags: php, forms, validation

```
//index.php

    $username=$password=$confirm_pass=$admin_type=$email="";
    $pass_exists=$con_pass_exists=$errview="";
    $errarr=array();

    ......//Verification and error push//........

    //assigning variable and error push
    if(isset($_POST["username"]) && !empty($_POST["username"])){
        $username=$_POST["username"];
    }else{
        array_push($errarr,"Username Field is Empty!!!");
    }

    if(count(errarr)>=0){
    $errview="<div class='errors'>";
      $errview.="<ul>";
      foreach ($errarr as $error){
          $errview.="<li>".$error."</li>";
      }
      $errview.="</ul>";
      $errview.="</div>";

      echo $errview;
      add_form();
    }

//html
      <form action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']) ?>"method="post" id="add_form">
          <span class="title">Username</span><input value="<?php if(isset($username))echo $username; ?>" tabindex="1" type="text" class="username" name="username">

          ......other elemenets.........
      </form>
```

I want to keep the values in some input fields if errors are found after submission. i even tried using $_GLOBAL[] for making the variable global scope. HOw can i make it happen?

Comment: What is your error? btw, I noticed this syntax problem here: if(count(errarr))...

Comment: that syntax was my mis while posting here. It doesn't show any error by php. The fields are empty everytime i submit the form and error occus

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it using direct $_POST rather than variable

```
<input value="<?php if(isset($_POST["username"]))echo $_POST["username"]; ?>" tabindex="1" type="text" class="username" name="username">
```

But i wonder why the variable assignment didn't work?

Answer (score 0):

Since you use method = post you could do something like this:

```
if (isset($_POST['username']) {
  // Form is submitted and we have a value.
  $username = $_POST['username'];
}
else {
  // Not a form submission, so we don't have a value.
  $username = '';
}
```

Then you can display error messages, and set the value back into the form:

```
<input value="<?php echo $username; ?>">
```

Comment: i can display error msgs but the $username variable isn't echoed on value attribute

Comment: Added the part where you could echo the value to the form again. If there are post values the value is echoed, of not a empty string.